# Flutter: How to resolve Error importing package:http/http.dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I am very new to `Flutter`, and stuck at the following error:

```
package:http/http.dart That library is in a package that is not known.
```

Maybe you forgot to mention it in your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Please help in resolving this error.

Comment: that package is part of flutter and should not show an error if you import it. To help you, you should post your relevant parts of the pubspec.yaml and .dart-File

Comment: The package is not a part of flutter but it is distributed via pub.

Answer (score 100):

Go to your `pubspec.yaml` file , and add the `http` dependency:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: any
```

Remember, the indentation must be the same as 'flutter' or 'cupertino_icons'

And don't forget to run this command in your terminal :

```
flutter packages get
```

Comment: And don't for get to `pub get` or `flutter packages get` after saving.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037356/what-is-the-difference-between-flutter-packages-get-and-flutter-pub-get](apparently) `flutter pub` is just an alias to `flutter packages`

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem. You just have to add latest http dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`

Here is the full code,

```
  dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter

      http: ^0.12.0+1

      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

Don't forget to change verson no. of http
To check latest version of http click [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http#-installing-tab-)

If you are running app directly from command line then you could also do:

with Flutter:

```
$ flutter packages get
```

with pub:

```
$ pub get
```

Answer (score 13):

I've found that, when in VS Code, you might need to restart the editor to get it to see the new http module that 'pub get' pulled in.  You can have your .dart code and pubspec.yaml exactly right but you still get the compiler/lint error.

Comment: this worked for me after installing the package using `flutter pub add http` and imported it like this: `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` i still get compiler error, closed my folder and open it up again in Vs Code, error's gone and editor shows warning for unused import only.

Answer (score 10):

You need to import like this:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Answer (score 7):

1.Install http package

```
flutter pub add http
```

2.check pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies: 
  http: ^0.13.4
```

3.Import in file

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
```

**[Reference](https://pub.dev/packages/http/install)**

Answer (score 5):

add below to pubspec.ymel  file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: ^0.12.0+1
```

use flutter [pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) to find the latest version

call

```
flutter packages get
```

Answer (score 4):

just got to pubspec.yaml file and tweak some changes in file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

 http:
```

under dependencies section just add http like in code description .

flutter will automatically resolve it and will add updated version of http .

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the http dependency in the `pubspec.yaml` file as shown below:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

Please take note of the indentation. After doing the above, run the below command in your terminal:

```
flutter packages get
```

As at the time of writing this, the latest http version is 0.12.0+2. You can learn more by visiting this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/http#-installing-tab-).

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: any
```

then:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

Finally:

```
flutter packages get
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:**

`dependencies:
   http: ^0.12.1`

**2. install it :**

`$ flutter pub get`

**3. Now in your Dart code, you can use:**

`import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

Answer (score 1):

-Just run this below command in your project directory to install http module

flutter pub add http

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Add below to pubspec.yaml file

```
  dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0+1
```

Or Just add http

```
dependencies:
http:
```

flutter will automatically used latest version of http .

> Then use pub get

Answer (score 0):

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
http: ^0.12.2

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

flutter:

uses-material-design: true
assets:
- images/

try to update the sdk versions and then pub get or flutter pub get to get the packages get install

Answer (score 0):

**just add in pubspec.yaml**

```
http: ^0.12.0+2
```

like as

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

and run in terminal

```
flutter pub get
```

finally add in class

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Answer (score 0):

When I got this issue, I just close the project from Android Studio `(File -> Close Project)`. And then open it again.

That works for me.

Simply just `Restart` the project.

**But** Make sure to add the certain dependency to the `pubspec.yaml` file and do `pub get`.

Answer (score -1):

You first find 'dependencies:' in `pubspec.yaml`
then under 'dependencies:' type `http: ^0.12.0+2` and then press ctrl + s to run get packages.

sample:

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

Answer (score -1):

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

http: any

Answer (score -2):

http: 
have to be align with the other dependencies.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to help the OP. Please clarify and elaborate.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue although I had the latest http package in Pubspec.yaml file. This error was still in there I did these 2 steps and error was resolved.

1. Remove import 'dart:_http'; if it is there
2. Add import 'dart:convert';