# Flutter packages get does not install new package in android studio

Tags: flutter, dart, http, package, dependencies

I am currently experiencing situation when i install dependencies it never get dowloaded in dart packages . When looking into it deeper, I've found that the packages never actually install themselves into the flutter packages folder.

The response I'm getting is exit code 0, with no error actual being reported.

When I put in my import 'package:http/http.dart'; it just shows up as a problem.
i tried to clean the flutter , restart the flutter but it did't work for me.

Comment: have you tried opening a terminal with admin/sudo rights and running flutter pub get?

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462488/flutter-how-to-resolve-error-importing-packagehttp-http-dart

Comment: also import it like this: import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;